# Ionic: unable to import contacts using $cordovaContacts in ios app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.    I have installed `$cordovaContacts` plugin via   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts`.

Previously its working fine and i am able to view my contacts but suddenly its not working i have not change my code.

I have reinstalled it but no luck. Here is my code

```
var opts = {
        multiple: true,
        fields:  [ 'displayName', 'name' ]
        };    
$cordovaContacts.find(opts).then(function(allContacts) { 
                                     $scope.ct = allContacts;
                                       alert($scope.ct);

                                     });
```

Please help me where i am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this is iOS related issue, why you are using Android tag?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check error in console from console.log

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
             $scope.labelList=contacts;
          };
          function onError(contactError) {
            alert(contactError);
          };
          var options = {};
          options.multiple = true;
          console.log(options.multiple);
          $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(onSuccess, onError);
        };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have also  tried this code alert `contactError` . Well i have resolve this problem,    in my iPhone app permission was disabled that's why its not working